# jersey 2.3.1 and spring integration compatibility issues

Tags: jersey-2.0

I am trying to create restful service project setup which will use jersey and spring. i downloaded initially jersey1.8 dependent jars  also i got jersey-spring-1.8 and i used com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet as jersey servlet and this setup worked well without any issues.

Now i was asked to use latest jersey version that is jersey2.3.1, so i downloaded jersey2.3.1 dependent jars like (jersey-container-servlet-core-2.3.1,jersey-container-servlet-2.3.1 etc). Now the problem is with jersey-spring which will have com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet, i downloaded jar from maven repository ie jersey-spring3-2.3.1.jar but it does not contain that above SpringServlet.So can any one please tell me what is the corresponding jersey-spring jar or am i missing anything here.

Note i tried to use jersey2.3.1 related jars with jersey-spring-1.8, but now i got exception saying com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer is missing. so there is some jar compatible issue.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed with jersey2.3.1 and spring integration?

Comment: Use maven, it will get all the dependencies you need.

Comment: Thanks Amir for your input, I was not able to download the jars due to firewall issue in my organization.Anyway i got appropriate example applications from jersey and got the jars. But the actual problem that i was struggling is due to there is a change in spring support for jersey 2.x vs jersey 1.x in 2.x onwards that springservlet is not available, but there are different way to achive spring integration via injections. https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in jersey 2.x and spring integration we can not define resources and providers in spring beans as we used to do in jersey 1.x and spring integration.
look at the below links.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1957   https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html

so there is no com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet in jersey 2.x

Comment: FYI, I believe the first link, for JERSEY-1957, is now in https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/2229

Answer (score 10):

The *com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet* has become now *org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer*

See this post https://www.codepedia.org/ama/restful-web-services-example-in-java-with-jersey-spring-and-mybatis/ for a complete explanation of Jersey2 and Spring 3 integration.

Answer (score 3):

With Jersey 2.x, `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` would be servlet class to be used.

In addition to `javax.ws.rs.Application` as an `init-param` option to the servlet, one can also have `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` as its parameter.

Below is a code snippet, how it would be in `web.xml` :

> ```
> <!-- Jersey Servlet -->
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
>     <!-- Register resources and providers -->
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
>         <param-value>com.jersey.series.spring.integration.service</param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> ```

And in Spring `applicationContext.xml` include :

> ```
> <!-- scans packages to find and register beans within the application context -->
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.jersey.series.spring.integration" />
> ```

Hope this helps.