# Spring Jersey 2.7: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, jersey

I am referring to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/) article

My `web.xml` looks like

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InventoryApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>com.org.me_services.inventory.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InventoryApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and maven dependencies as

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!--
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
-->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <!--<artifactId>*</artifactId>-->
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.test.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

the resource class is

```
@Component
@Path("/inv")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public Response hello() {
        System.out.println("REQUEST RECEIVED");
        return Response.accepted().build();

    }
}
```

I deploy this on `Tomcat 7x` and see errors as

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Marking servlet com.org.me_services.inventory.services.InventoryApplication as unavailable
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 04, 2014 9:52:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Servlet /services threw load() exception
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
```

Comment: It is jar dependency problem  
please Refer this link  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206466/jersey-2-3-1-and-spring-integration-compatibility-issues

Comment: The article refers to Spring with Jersey 1.x You are using Jersey 2.x which will not work with the integration you are trying. Either switch to Jersey 1.x or check out this http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/02/implementing-jersey-2-spring-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Put all jars inside the lib folder, don't select external jars from build path,
you have to put your all requred jars inside

> WebContent\WEB-INF\lib